# Read a protein fasta file and splitting the read string at Arginine(R) and then blastp the peptides to get the matches?

Tags: split, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta, bioperl

I have the following fasta file:

```
'>gi|277456704|dbj|ID_P|Gene name LLL
MDGFAGSLDDSISAASTSDVQDRLSALESRVQQQEDEITVLKAALADVLRRLAISEDHVASVKKSVSSKV
YRRKHQELQAMQMELQSPEYKLSKLRTSTIMTDYNPNYCFAGKTSSISDLKEVPRKNITLIRGLGHGAFG
EVYEGQVSGMPNDPSPLQVAVKTLPEVCSEQDELDFLMEALIISKFNHQNIVRCIGVSLQSLPRFILLEL
MAGGDLKSFLRETRPRPSQPSSLAMLDLLHVARDIACGCQYLEENHFIHRDIAARNCLLTCPGPGRVAKI
GDFGMARDIYRASYYRKGGCAMLPVKWMPPEAFMEGIFTSKTDTWSFGVLLWEIFSLGYMPYPSKSNQEV
LEFVTSGGRMDPPKNCPGPVYRIMTQCWQHQPEDRPNFAIILERIEYCTQDPDVINTALPIEYGPLVEEE

'>gi|27704|dbj|ID_Y|Gene name JJJ
MDGFAGSLDDSISAASTSDVQDRLSALESRVQQQEDEITVLKAALADVLRRLAISEDHVASVKKSVSSKG
SELRGGYGDPGRLPVGSGLCSASRARLPGHVAADHPPAVYRRKHQELQAMQMELQSPEYKLSKLRTSTIM
TDYNPNYCFAGKTSSISDLKEVPRKNITLIRGLGHGAFGEVYEGQVSGMPNDPSPLQVAVKTLPEVCSEQ
DELDFLMEALIISKFNHQNIVRCIGVSLQSLPRFILLELMAGGDLKSFLRETRPRPSQPSSLAMLDLLHV
ARDIACGCQYLEENHFIHRDIAARNCLLTCPGPGRVAKIGDFGMARDIYRASYYRKGGCAMLPVKWMPPE

'>gi|2097704|dbj|ID_X|Gene name X
MDGFAGSLDDSISAASTSDVQDRLSALESRVQQQEDEITVLKAALADVLRRLAISEDHVASVKKSVSSKG
QPSPRAVIPMSCITNGSGANRKPSHTSAVSIAGKETLSSAAKSGTEKKKEKPQGQREKKEESHSNDQSPQ
IRASPSPQPSSQPLQIHRQTPESKNATPTKSIKRPSPAEKSHNSWENSDDSRNKLSKIPSTPKLIPKVTK
TADKHKDVIINQEGEYIKMFMRGRPITMFIPSDVDNYDDIRTELPPEKLKLEWAYGYRGKDCRANVYLLP
TGEIVYFIASVVVLFNYEERTQRHYLGHTDCVKCLAIHPDKIRIATGQIAGVDKDGRPLQPHVRVWDSVT
LSTLQIIGLGTFERGVGCLDFSKADSGVHLCVIDDSNEHMLTVWDWQRKAKGAEIKTTNEVVLAVEFHPT
```

I would like to loop through the FASTA , split the protein sequence at all the 'R' it comes across, this will generate peptides and then blastp the peptides. Get the results from blastp and store the blastp results in a separate file for each protein ID in the fasta file.
I am not particular about what language is used. I want to learn how this can be done so that i can build more functionality on top of it.
Thanks!

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org

Comment: @Pierre : Thanks for recommending biostars but i donot feel comfortable posting on that site since the moderators are too rude and either downvote the question or close it.

Comment: your comment was discussed here: http://www.biostars.org/p/73956/

Comment: @Pierre Thats great! Thank you for that. Just look at the simple answer that was given to me below which directed me towards finding the solution. Not exactly the type of response where the first question is what have you done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [Biopython](http://biopython.org), you can [parse the FASTA file](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc11) into [Sequence](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc16) objects, [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at "R", then [BLAST over the internet](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc86) or [run BLAST locally](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc87). You can take the results (expressed as [SeqRecords](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord), and [output them to a FASTA file](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#Sequence_Output) by [iterating over each record](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-module.html#parse).

The documentation has plenty of code samples you can use to piece together what you're looking for.